# Marking subject/object that is not a pronoun?

Tags: morphology, marking

I've recently been on a kind of a morphology seminar and was informed that it is not an uncommon phenomenon for languages to specifically mark subjects and objects which are not pronouns - an example being the Coptic language.

Unfortunately all of my internet queries upon this subject have been to no avail because I do not know the name of this phenomenon. Has anyone here ever heard of something like this and would they be able to put a name on it?

(EDIT)

Some example sentences illustrating this kind of marking in Coptic:

> eseqep-paibōk (FUT-she FUT-catch (-) NPOBJ-that-slave)
>
> nerepaiqam napōt (COND-NPSUB-that-bull COND-run)
>
> šansotmk (PRES-we-hear-you)
>
> erepennēb nempefjaje ewem-phalēt (FUT-NPSUB-our-master and-his-enemy FUT-eat (-) NPOBJ-bird)
>
> erepjaje ehotbs (FUT-NPSUB-enemy FUT-kill-she)
>
> šarepairōme wōm (PRES-NPSUB-that-man eat)
>
> nesnabel-pekqam (COND-she-COND-untie (-) NPOBJ-your-bull)

It was said that *-rep-* marks a non-pronoun subject (glossed NPSUB) and *p-* a non-pronoun object (glossed NPOBJ).

Comment: Does this relate to what you are talking about? https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Chris_Reintges/publication/237956174_Aspects_of_the_morphosyntax_of_subjects_and_objects_in_Coptic_Egyptian/links/5469dda80cf2397f782dd3ed/Aspects-of-the-morphosyntax-of-subjects-and-objects-in-Coptic-Egyptian.pdf

Comment: Inflectional forms of nouns are said to be 'case-marked'. Turkish is a decent example of a language which does that.

Comment: @BillJ. The question is about languages which do not mark pronouns for case.

Comment: @fdb I'm aware of that. Which is why I mentioned Turkish, which takes case-markings on nouns.

Comment: @BillJ. And on pronouns too.

Comment: @fdb The OP did not specify only languages that mark nouns but not pronouns. Perhaps the OP could make that clear. Turkish marks objects that are not pronouns (as well as the latter of course)

Comment: @BillJ. I see that now. I was assuming this was a sensible question, not a banal one. Thousands of languages mark nouns for case. I am voting to close this one.

Comment: @sumelic I'm afraid I can't say I found what I was looking for in your paper, though I have to say the paper is on quite a high level, so it might have as well slipped over my head. If someone could name this phenomenon, I would be most greatful.

Comment: Hi! Sorry that the link wasn't helpful. As others have indicated, your question is somewhat unclear. Can you remember what type of marker this was? Is it like an affix that attaches to a verb? One that attaches to a noun? I am not familar with Coptic and I'm having a hard time imagining the exact nature of a language having something to "specifically mark subjects and objects which are not pronouns" (unless as fdb suggests you are just talking about grammatical case?)

Comment: As for the other two, I thank you for your replies but regret to inform you that the issue at hand has not a thing to do with case-marking. The inquiry is about precisely marking a subject or object that is not a pronoun. To put it more precisely: a certain morpheme has to precede each subject that explicitly refers to an entity, id est is not pronoun.

Comment: This is still rather confusing. The question refers to languages that "specifically mark subjects and objects which are not pronouns"; your most recent comment instead says "a certain morpheme has to precede each subject that ... is not [a] pronoun". Are you saying there is one morpheme that precedes non-pronominal subjects, and another, separate morpheme that precedes non-pronominal objects? Is it an article?

Comment: (My understanding is that articles usually are not used with pronouns; this is true also in English)

Comment: I understand that I might have not made myself clear enough. I do have some examples at hand, albeit written in a most exotic phonetic transcription, which is the reason I didn't have them put up in the first place. Formulating text on this phone is extremely tedious (as is shadowed in the time it took me to write a reply) so I shall refrain from posting them until I get acces to a computer. Again thank you for your interest.

Comment: To clarify: I probably forgot about this back in 2018, but looking back, it seems that it indeed could have been an article. Anyway, I found the example sentences while cleaning some old files, so I'll append them to the original question for completion.

Comment: Are those examples Coptic? I don’t know anything about Coptic, but the Wikipedia article on it does mention a lot of forms being “with a nonpronominal subject”, so it seems likely to be correct. This isn’t a form of marking that had ever occurred to me before, though, so I can’t help you with a name for it.

Comment: Yes, they are Coptic, I probably should have worded that better. I believe the person lecturing said that many languages tend to mark this "nonpronominality" which then led me to believe they meant articles but avoided using the term for some reason. Granted, it does not happen often that subjects and objects take different articles (or that they should be infixes, I suppose?).

Comment: Also, if someone knows how to better gloss this abomination of a syntax, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Note: I don't know any Coptic.

-rep- and -p- both share the element [p]. Coptic is supposed to have have a prefixed definite article with the consonant [p] for masculine nouns. This suggests to me that -rep- is not a single morpheme, but is further subdivisible. "pai" seems to mean "that".  You could look at whether equivalently structured sentences with a feminine noun contain -ret- instead of -rep-. Likewise, this would mean that glossing -p- as an object marker seems like a pretty bad decision, unless there are other factors that I don't know about.

The Wikipedia article on [Coptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_language#Tense/aspect/mood_inflection) says "Coptic has a very large number of distinct tense-aspect-mood categories, expressed by particles which are either before the verb or before the subject".

One of these is given as "nere" (before an NP) or nef- (with a third-person masculine pronominal subject). The article seems to analyze "re" as part of the particle, not part of the following noun phrase.

Note that in your examples, the gloss "NPSUB" always occurs directly after a gloss for a TAM category (like COND, FUT, PRES).

I think the gloss you have for the sentence "ere-p-jaje e-hotb-s", "FUT-NPSUB-enemy FUT-kill-she", is inaccurate in that Wikipedia suggests that a pronoun suffixed to a verb functions as an object pronoun. So the final -s- seems to mean "her" rather than "she" (I guess the translation would be "The enemy will kill her"?). The gloss I would suggest is something like "FUT.NP-DEF-enemy FUT-kill-3s.F".

Differential inflection of words based on whether they are used with pronouns vs. noun phrases does show up in other languages. Welsh has prepositions that inflect when used with pronouns and also shows different patterns of verb agreement with pronouns vs. noun phrases (e.g. only pronouns trigger plural verb agreement).

Comment: I think you’re right about the ‘she’ being object rather than subject – as best I can make out from the limited info in the Wikipedia article, _hotb_ should be the pronominal state of the verb, which is used with pronominal objects. This in fact means that Coptic uses morphologically distinct forms for pronouns and non-pronouns in the TAM marker slot (NP _ere-_ vs P _e-_), in the subject prefix slot (NP _Ø-_ vs P _ət-_), in the object suffix slot (NP _-Ø_ vs P _-s_) **and** in the verbal stem itself (NP obj _hōtəb/hətb_ [?] vs P _hotb_). Four places. That’s a bit!

Comment: It is definitely possible that -p- is a masculine definite article, which would make all nouns in the examples masculine. I analysed "pai" as "p-ai", i.e. NPOBJ-that, but it could be DEF-that as well.

Comment: "ra" is then part of a longer TAM-marker, huh? The ones given on Wikipedia don't seem to correspond very well to those in the example sentences though. I suppose I must conclude that the examples (and the translations) I was given are not the best.

Comment: You're right about that sentence. I was given the translation in a language that lacks articles, so literally "Enemy will kill her." I wasn't sure how to gloss that because "s" (she) is not marked per se, but it is evident from its being suffixed as you described that it is the object.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I suppose that is the simplest way of putting it then, yes. Though I'm not sure where you got (NP Ø- vs P ət-) from? Also, I don't think there are any object suffixes, "s" is simply a 3s.f pronoun that is used as an object, as I understand it. There's definitely something strange going on with the verb stems as well but I chose not to copy those examples as it is quite distracting.

Comment: @GregorGajič Note that I said the object suffix _slot_, that is, the position after the verb stem where the object goes if there is a suffixed pronoun used as an object. If the object is a NP, this slot is empty; it’s only filled if the object is a pronoun (and similarly with subjects in the pre-stem subject prefix slot). The prefix form _ət-_ should have been _əs-_, that was just a typo; if it had been ‘she will kill the enemy’, it would presumably have been something like _ese-hōt(ə?)b əm-pə-jaje_ or _ese-hətb pə-jaje_, where you can see the _əs-_ form appear in the prefix _ese-_.